# SP2013 Search Multiple Host Header Site Collections

Tags: enterprise-search, host-named

Is it possible to have a search center at portalA.domain.com (or at its own host header site like search.domain.com) to return results from portalB.domain.com?

I have tested in my environment and observed that a Search Center only works within the host header it sits under.

Is there a setup/solution that can achieve "cross domain search"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me. You need to utilise Result Source and create a new Search Vertical.

Make sure the new Result Source is of the type "Remote SharePoint Site", and provide the HNSC URL you want to search for. It has to be HTTPS, and of course a certificate for the HNSC. In the query, set the Path to HNSC, don't worry if it doesn't return any results in the test section. Just ok and use it in your search result web part.

Reference on how to create a new Search Vertical: 
http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/11/13/how-to-add-a-customized-search-vertical-to-your-search-results-page-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx